# In Xamarin forms, How can you make selected option in picker not visible in other pickers?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]I have 7 similar pickers with same options.  Right now user can select 
    the same option from picker1 that it's already been selected in picker2.  I want if user selected in picker not visible in picker2.

I have googled but no one seems to have ask this question it.

```
void drainxy1()
{
drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add("1");
drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add("2");
drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add("3");
drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add("4");       
}
void drainxy2()
{
drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add("1");
drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add("2");
drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add("3");
drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add("4");       
}
void drainxy3()
{
drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add("1");
drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add("2");
drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add("3");
drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add("4");       
}
void drainxy4()
{
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add("1");
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add("2");
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add("3");
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add("4");       
}
<Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker1" Title="Drain Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker2" Title="Drain Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker3" Title="Drain Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker4" Title="Drain Location" />
/*
Picker1= select from 1,2,3,4
user selects = 2
picker2= select from 1,3,4
user selects = 3
Picker3= select from 1,4
user selects = 1
picker4= select from 4
user selects = 4 */


void drain1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{           
drainlocationPicker2.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);            
drainlocationPicker3.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);              `   drainlocationPicker4.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);                
}
```

xamlfile

```
<Label x:Name="drain3Label" Text="Drain 3: " Grid.Column="0" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
<Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker3" Title="Drain Location" Grid.Column="1"
SelectedIndexChanged="drain3Handle_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Comment: you will need to add a handler to each picker that removes the selected item from all of the other pickers

Comment: what kind of handler?

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a simple demo about it.
Here is running GIF.

[image]

You can achieve by following code.I create a list that include all the items. Then achieve the SelectedIndexChanged as Jason's said.Note: Next, you need to judge the various actions of the user by yourselves.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<string> list;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        list.Add("3");
        list.Add("4");
        drainxy1();
        drainxy2();
        drainxy3();
        drainxy4();


        drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker2_SelectedIndexChanged;
        drainlocationPicker3.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker3_SelectedIndexChanged;
        drainlocationPicker4.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker4_SelectedIndexChanged;



    }

    private void DrainlocationPicker4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DrainlocationPicker3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        drainlocationPicker4.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker3.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void DrainlocationPicker2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        drainlocationPicker3.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIndex);
        drainlocationPicker4.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        drainlocationPicker2.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);
        drainlocationPicker3.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);
        drainlocationPicker4.Items.RemoveAt(drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex);

    }

    void drainxy1()
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    void drainxy2()
    {

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    void drainxy3()
    {

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    void drainxy4()
    {

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @hypnocool, This error means that drainlocationPicker3 did not have this index, do you add all the items to `drainlocationPicker3` like these code `void drainxy3()
    {

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }`

Comment: please explain what is this doing? drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged;  I check drain3 and it's all there.

Comment: `drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndexChanged += DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged` when you click the item in `drainlocationPicker1`, that you mean you have select the item, select index has been changed, so it will operate the `DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged` method. You can upload your demo(could reproduce this issue), I can help you to troubleshot this issue.

Comment: ok ran your code and it works but if I select "1" on picker1 Then picker 2,3,4 is missing "2". If I select "2" on picker1 Then picker 2,3,4 is missing "3".  If I select "3" on picker1 Then picker 2,3,4 is missing "4".  f I select "4" on picker1 Then an error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index  " like error photo above.

Comment: Please make sure index is start from 1 or 0, I don’t know what is your list, based on your description, you should make index-1 every time

Comment: I included the xaml file for the demo code giving errors

Comment: void drainxy1()
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

Comment: how to make sure index is start from 1 or 0?list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("0");
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        list.Add("3");

Comment: Ok now it works. i have to use Remove not RemoveAt.   So it will remove selected string. Thanks @Leon Lu  drainlocationPicker2.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);
            drainlocationPicker3.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);
            drainlocationPicker4.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, if the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, or you can share your solution and mark it as answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.